# How do I create the correct FIREBASE_CONFIG environment variable?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

I am attempting to write to CloudFirestore via my node/firebase app and have found the docs to be a little unclear. When I compile my app, the terminal states:

> Warning, FIREBASE_CONFIG environment variable is missing. Initializing
>   firebase-admin will fail

The firebase docs say I should run:

> firebase functions:config:set unknownthusarbitraryservicename.key="Unknown, Thus Arbitrary API Key"
>   unknownthusarbitraryservicename.id="The ClientID from generated private key"

I have generated a 'private key' and have discovered my 'client_id', however:

1. Where can I discover my service name? I've assumed 'someservice'
   is arbitrary, as I don't see one listed in the service account tab
   of the console. At present, I've chosen my project_id from the
   'generated_private_key.json' file.
2. Where can I find my API Key? No 'API Key' is listed in the 'generated_private_key.json'. I'm assuming this isn't arbitrary, but there are too many unknowns for me to proceed confidently.

An example of what I'm ultimately trying to accomplish:

```
    const admin = require('firebase-admin');
    const db = admin.firestore();

    admin.initializeApp({
        credential: admin.credential.cert(isThisMyServiceName),
        databaseURL: "https://my-databaseURL.firebaseio.com"
    });

    app.post('/', (req, res) => {
        var data = {
            name: 'Los Angeles',
            state: 'CA',
            country: 'USA'
        };

        var setDoc = db.collection('cities').doc('LA').set(data);
    }
```

Currently:

> firebase functions:config:get

returns:

```
{
  "unknownthusarbitraryservicename": {
    "id": "The ClientID from generated private key",
    "key": "Unknown, Thus Arbitrary API Key"
  }
}
```

But no firebase_config.json is created

  3. If the config.json file isn't auto-created, how should I register its existence for the node compiler?

Comment: Please edit the question to include the code you're trying to run, and how exactly you're trying to run it.

Comment: Edited as requested. I've also tried to be a bit more verbose around the specific issue

Comment: I don't see any code where you call admin.initializeApp().  This is very important.  See the documentation.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup#initialize_the_sdk

Comment: It was in there, just missed it for the question. With the exception of expressjs setup, CORS requirements and a get method, that's all it currently does.